# Accessing elements within a data structure

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

I've had a good search and am stumped.  It may be a simple answer, but after 80 hours of work so far this week, I just can't see it...

In my app I pass some variables to a Web Service, which passes back a single structure containing key/value pairs.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "it_submitcall.php",
    data: {callService: "getcall", callid: $("#callNumber").val()},
    dataType: "HTML",
    success: function(data){
        //do stuff here
    },
    error: function(data){
        // unable to communicate with web service stuff here
    }
});
```

The response I get back is

```
Array
(
    [CALLID] => 44497
    [CALLERNAME] => Chris
    [TEAMID] => 1175
)
```

How do I access the elements above in javascript?  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated...

Many thanks.

Comment: Is that the actual response text?

Comment: Have tried various ways of accessing an array, but keep getting back "undefined" in firebug console

Comment: That's the text version of a PHP Array right?

Comment: @phen - the variables are sent to a php pae via ajax and this is the response my php page gives, which is the returned structure from the Web Services.  Do I need to work on the data within the php page rather than JS?

Comment: Yes, the easiest way is probably to look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) - it demonstrates PHP functions to encode PHP objects as JSON, which can then be parsed by the JavaScript.

Comment: Then that is not a json representation so you can't parse it using the standard JSON module. Take a look at http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the PHP side use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to turn the Array into JSON e.g:

```
<?php
    $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Then on the JavaScript side use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get a JavaScript object back - in your case:

```
success: function(data){
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
},
```

Comment: on the php side:  $result = $client->__soapCall($wsdlOperation, array('parameters'=>$param));
            echo json_encode($result);

then on the JS side: var obj = JSON.parse(data);

to access the element: obj["CALLID"]

Many many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

As @phenomnomnominal notes, you can use `json_encode()` on a PHP object to turn it to JSON (and, notably, `json_decode()` to turn it from JSON to a PHP object)

Once you've got that down, nicely, PHP and JS "hash"-like objects act a lot alike (in PHP, we call these associative arrays and in JavaScript, object literals).

In php, you access an array `$your_var` like this:

```
$value = $your_var[ 'key' ];
```

You can also use variables:

```
$key = 'key';
$value = $your_var[ $key ];
```

In JavaScript, it's very similar:

```
var value = your_var[ 'key' ];
```

Alternatively:

```
var key = 'key';
var value = your_var[ key ];
```

And there's one more syntax that's helpful and more efficient when you don't need variable access to a key:

```
var value = your_var.key
```

Comment: This helped to clarify a couple points too...  Many thanks :)